# rails 3 - link_to to destroy not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a destroy link to my users controller, I am also using devise.

Here is my code -

#### View

```
<%= link_to 'Delete User?', child, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete #{child.full_name}?", :method => :delete, :class => "user-additional", :style => "font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;" %>
```

#### Controller

```
def destroy
 if @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.destroy
  respond_to do |format| 
    format.html { redirect_to account_index_path } 
    format.xml { head :ok } 
  end
 end
end
```

#### Routes

```
devise_for :users 
resources :users, :except => [:new]
```

The link translates to localhost:3000/users/10

When clicked this opens the users show instead of deleting them

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you know if the link is using a GET or DELETE request? I know you have method specified there, but when you say the link resolves to localhost:3000/users/10, that could mean a couple of things. You can check by using an inspection tool like Firebug or Chrome Inspector.

Comment: Is JavaScript enabled? Is the `rails.js` file included in the application layout file? What about the prototype JS lib? If jQuery and prototype JS libs are being used, try using only prototype?

Comment: Probably you have wrong link to script file in head of your layout.

Comment: link_to is a bad practice if it is not a get request, as it can be opened in a new tap... clicked by web crawlers ... etc
user button_to instead as it creates a form

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Destructive actions should be performed as a form submission - http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html#checklist

use `button_to` (passing a `:method => :delete`) instead and style the button appropriately.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been 2 hours around this problem, and your answer save my work day.

Answer (score 27):

Actually I just had the exactly same problem yesterday

Try this:

```
<%= button_to "delete", your_object, :method=>:delete, :class=>:destroy %>
```

It works (for me at least)

Comment: Worked for me too but don't why its not working with link_to. jquery was automatically included by rails 4.2. I'm using ruby 2.0.0. Javascript enabled  in Google chrome content settings.

Comment: Did this with a nested object (passed the child_object) and it deleted the parent object, instead.

Answer (score 9):

In case that you are using jQuery instead of Prototype, you are probably missing a javascript file.

You can find details on how to add it to your project from the [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) GitHub page or from [episode 205](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript) of the Railscasts.

Comment: +1 despite this not being marked 'correct', it pointed me towards ujs, which was the last thing I need to ditch prototype for jQuery. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

At a guess I think it is because in Rails 3, unobtrusive javascript is now used for functionality such as this (Rails 2 would output a bunch of nasty inline javascript for your code, Rails 3 puts the javascript in an external file, and uses HTML5 `data-` attributes to interact with that.)

To solve this you need to include `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` in your page header to reference the external javascript. It also deals with XSS issues.

Some details here: [Delete link sends "Get" instead of "Delete" in Rails 3 view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774925/delete-link-sends-get-instead-of-delete-in-rails-3-view)

Comment: I dont think its the js I just tried this - <%= link_to 'Delete User?', child, :method => :delete %> and no luck

Comment: @Maruccio, it is now, but that was correct then. Anyway I'll edit to keep this answer up to date.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, make sure you have something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // this allows jquery to be called along with scriptaculous and YUI without any conflicts
  // the only difference is all jquery functions should be called with $j instead of $
  // e.g. $jQ('#div_id').stuff instead of $('#div_id').stuff
  var $jQ = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Comment: assignin it to jQ didnt work for me, I just called jQuery.noConflict(); and then I would use it like jQuery(document) instead of $(document) more info here: http://yehudakatz.com/2007/01/31/using-jquery-in-rails-part-i/

Comment: using the jQ=JQuery.noConflict(); makes jQuery available from $jQ instead of using $, which helps making calls to jQuery and javascript/ajax not conflict with each other. I had this same issue, and this line of code made my delete link work again. Maybe your problem was somewhere else.

Comment: it did solve my problem. The only thing I was pointing out was that using $jQ didn't work for me.

Comment: looks like my fault, I misstyped the variable name, it should be:
var $jQ = jQuery.noConflict();
I'll edit the post and correct it, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

1. follow the steps in the installation part [rails/jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs#installation)
2. add **<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>** in your layout file.

Comment: this seems to be answering a different question

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't included jquery and jquery-ujs in your app ,  the default link_to default coming with scaffold wont work!

I had the same issue.It got solved after including both these js!

Answer (score 1):

Also if you get this problem in production mode, it may be because you have not compiled the assets. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Comment: That is the real reason, it is the command: RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me with confirmation message.

```
<%= button_to 'Destroy', {action: :destroy, id: version.id},  onclick: 'return confirm("Are you sure?")', method: :delete %>
```