# ruby on rails - link_to() problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made this link in order to destroy a comment :

```
    <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.post, comment],
    :confirm => 'Are you sure?',  :method => :delete %>
```

this suppose to send to the destroy action in the comments_controller.

the problem is that it searches for the 'show' action, Instead of the 'destroy' action :

```
   Unknown action

   The action 'show' could not be found for CommentsController
```

Do you think you know why it does that?

Thanks,

Oded

edit: problem solved I used 'button_to'

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606860/rails-3-link-to-to-destroy-not-working/4607179#4607179

Comment: I use link_to in combination with :method => :delete all the time. Never used button_to for that. What version of Rails are you using? And what Javascript framework are you using? Prototype or JQuery?

Comment: i agree, i use link_to with :method => :delete all the time. I suspect you might be on Rails 3 but not including the javascript files.

Answer (score 5):

**Rails 3:**

When you use JQuery, make sure you have the right rails.js file (https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs). When you use Prototype, the correct rails.js file is already installed. Also, make sure the following is added in your layout head:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

And also make sure that both the JS framework and the rails.js file is being loaded.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery", "rails" %>
# or
<%= javascript_include_tag "prototype", "rails" %>
```

*Just a side-note - You can also point to the Googleapis link: http://scriptsrc.net/.*

When you use `:method => :delete` inside a link, the following HTML will be created:

```
<a href="/comments/1" data-method="delete">Click me!</a>
```

As you see, the HTML5 data- attribute is being used. The rails.js file automaitcally puts click events on links with these attributes. When `data-method="delete"` is set, the request will be done with the DELETE HTTP method. So clicking it will destroy the comment. Also, setting :confirm will create a data-confirm attribute which does what you would expect.

**Rails 2:**

When you use Prototype, the `:method => :delete` thing will work automatically. Just make sure you include the right Javascript files:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

When using JQuery you should install the 'jrails' plugin (https://github.com/aaronchi/jrails). It allows you to use the same Prototype helpers for JQuery. The plugin uses an old version of JQuery, so make sure you update that one.

I don't know for sure if the :method attribute uses Prototype in Rails 2 or just regular Javascript. So it could be that you don't even need Prototype or JQuery for the :method attribute in Rails 2.

As I said in the comment: I never use button_to for DELETE links. You can just as easily get it working with link_to. And as far as I know it's the helper most people use when creating these kind of links. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: The requirement of javascript or a browser that supports data-attributes is cause for concern.

Comment: Just tested UJS with data-attributes with IE6 and it works great. The HTML5 data-attributes aren't supported, but you can still access them with Javascript. And about the Javascript concern: it depends on what kind of users you are targeting. Most users have JS enabled (95% according to w3schools) and JS is being used more and more (even for core functions). Basecamp even shows a big alert message when a user doesn't have JS enabled, telling that a lot of features won't work. It all depends on who you're targeting. :)

Answer (score 1):

> ERROR: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/jquery.js")

Solution, download: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.js

> ERROR: AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for CommentsController)

Solution, download: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/raw/master/src/rails.js

In rails 3.1.0 save the above js files to app/public/javascripts/
Rename or remove your existing js files.

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved this problem in my own App (rails 3). I followed the steps for rails 3 and, the most important issue, installed the correct `rails.js` file in my `public/javascripts` folder. It didn't work until I've installed `rails.js`.

The one i chose is this:
https://raw.github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/master/src/rails.js

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this same issue with Rails 3. I'm using jQuery with the updated rails.js file. What fixed it for me was something simple - use :method => :delete, not :method => :destroy.

```
=link_to( 'delete account', user_admin_path(current_user.id), :confirm => "Deleting your account is irreversible!! Are you sure you wish to continue?", :method => :delete )
```

And in the header I have:

```
= javascript_include_tag "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js", "jquery.colorbox-min", "jquery.validate.min", "rails"
```

Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you reference `//= require jquery` and `//= require jquery_ujs` (in that order) in your application.js file, in `\app\assets\javascripts`.