# Delete link doesn't work but button does

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem very similar to this one: [rails 3 - link_to to destroy not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606860/rails-3-link-to-to-destroy-not-working)

But delete/destroy links do not work; I simply get redirected to the show page of the object. When I make a button for delete, it all works fine. But I'd like to understand why. Does anyone know?

I seems to be related to some .js files I am using/calling.

```
<!-- This link doesn't work -->
<%= link_to('Delete', post, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete) %>-->

<!-- This button does work -->
<%= button_to "delete", post, :method=>:delete, :class=>:destroy, :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>
```

Post Controller

```
def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.destroy

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to(posts_url) }
  format.xml  { head :ok }
end
```

end

UPDATE
After doing some further research it seem that everyone else having a similiar issue has included the following jquery library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/dragdrop.js"></script>
```

But I still don't know what the issue is...

LOG

```
Started GET "/posts/7" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Jul 12 08:34:06 -0400 2011
Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"7"}
Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = 7 LIMIT 1
SQL (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments".post_id = 7)
Rendered posts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (116.5ms)
```

HTML generated

```
<a href="/posts/17" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>
```

UPDATE: I've found that removing `<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>` fixes my problem. But I don't understand why. Is there a known conflict between jquery1.5.1 and rails 3.0.7?

Comment: Could you please provide the first two lines of your log-file for each request? (the ones showing `Processing` and `Parameters`). Also the generated HTML output could be of interest.

Comment: Is what I posted above what you meant by the "log-file"? Sorry, I'm very new to rails...

Comment: Ya, this is the log I needed. Seems that the link does not send `DELETE` but `GET` so the action `show` is called instead of `destroy`. Please also provide the generated HTML source for the link.

Comment: Ok, I just posted the HTML generated above. Seems kinda odd that it the href would be to "/posts/17"...

Comment: I've also just found that removing the following script from my application.html.erb file fixes everything: <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: Seems that something with unobstrusive javascript translation does not work with this version of jquery. You can use the functionality of your browser right click on that link -> "inspect element" to see what is actually done to the DOM by jquery.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you include these in your application layout:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag(:defaults) %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

Comment: I do have both of those in my application layout.

Answer (score 1):

In my case adding

```
<%= javascript_include_tag(:defaults) %>
```

did not work. However explicitly defining java script files did the trick

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'prototype' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

Not sure yet why :defaults tag didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Rails will automatically load jquery for you if you have jquery-rails gem loaded via your Gemfile (this is the default rails configuration). It is then loaded via:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag(:defaults) %>
```

Have a look at app/assets/javascripts/application.js for the code that tells rails to add jquery via assets:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

By trying to load another copy of jquery via this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

You have caused a clash of jquery instances, the effect of which will be that neither will work.