# Adding a Twitter Bootstrap button icon to button_to in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am working through the [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) book but I have been using Twitter Bootstrap instead of the custom styling from the book. I am having trouble adding an icon through GLyphonics to the **button_to** method. My code looks like this:

```
<%= button_to <i class="icon-search icon-white">Add To Cart</i>, 
              line_items_path(product_id: product), 
              class: "btn btn-success" %>
```

I have tried quite a few variations but can't seem to get it to work correctly.

Comment: do you know if any of the Twitter Bootstrap CSS is working? My guess is it's a file path issue, perhaps the glyphicon isn't in the right folder. If you just do pure HTML, no Ruby, does the following show the search icon?: `<i class="icon-search icon-white">Add To Cart</i>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you have an issue with your quotes:

```
<%= button_to raw("<i class=\"icon-search icon-white\">Add To Cart</i>"), 
          line_items_path(product_id: product), 
          class: "btn btn-success" %>
```

Enclose the label of the button in double quotes, escape the double quotes in your `i` tag, and finally, wrap everything into a `raw()` call to ensure the HTML is properly displayed.

Alternatively you can use `html_safe`:

```
<%= button_to "<i class=\"icon-search icon-white\">Add To Cart</i>".html_safe, 
          line_items_path(product_id: product), 
          class: "btn btn-success" %>
```

---

good point from @jordanpg: you can't have HTML in the value of a button, so his solution is more appropriate and should get the approved status.
the `html_safe`part remains valid though.

Comment: AHH! That was the problem. I thought it was something related to that but I was just doing it wrong. Thanks a bunch Pierre.

Comment: This answer is wrong and doesn't work. @jordanpg's answer below is the correct one.

Comment: Does NOT work. I'm using Rails 4.2.6 and tested both raw() and .html_safe and none of them worked.

Answer (score 58):

I'm not sure how the OP got this to work, but Rails `button_to` generates an `<input type='submit' />` element, which does not allow for HTML in the value field.

See also: [input type="submit" Vs button tag are they interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117639/input-type-submit-vs-button-tag-are-they-interchangeable)

The best alternative in this situation is to force `link_to` to PUT (or POST):

```
<%= link_to raw("<i class=\"icon-search icon-white\">Add To Cart</i>"), 
          line_items_path(product_id: product), 
          class: "btn btn-success",
          method: :put %>
```

Comment: Except when we're talking about a link/button for deleting. We need a button to SUBMIT for the HTML method to work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606860/rails-3-link-to-to-destroy-not-working

Comment: The button_to method is preferable to link_to. The reasons are explained [here](http://blog.markusproject.org/?p=3890). See my answer for how to use it with an icon.

Comment: For what it's worth, the link shared by @DanT no longer returns a result, so here's the last snapshot from the webarchive:
https://web.archive.org/web/20160313112835/http://blog.markusproject.org/?p=3890

Answer (score 39):

You can add the icon as a child element:

```
<%= button_to button_path, method: :delete do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Using raw() or #html_safe still did not work for me.

I am using a helper method to create a button_to flag content. Ended up using the following in my helper method (path is defined beforehand):

```
form_tag path, :method => :post do
  button_tag do
    content_tag :i, 'Flag as inappropriate', :class => 'icon-flag flag_content'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

I used this one and it works fine for me :

```
<%= link_to(line_items_path(product_id: product),
    method: :put,
    class: 'btn btn-success') do %>
    <%= content_tag('i', nil, class: 'icon-search icon-white') %> Add To Cart
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: working answer, but the file issue described in the comments is probably more the cause

Comment: Note: this answer only works with JavaScript enabled. If the browser has JavaScript disabled, the link will be called via the GET method.

Answer (score 4):

I am using this helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def glyph(*names)
   content_tag :i, nil, class: names.map{|name| "icon-#{name.to_s.gsub('_','-')}" }
  end
end
```

Example:

```
glyph(:share_alt)
=> <i class="icon-share-alt"></i>
```

and

```
glyph(:lock, :white)
=> <i class="icon-lock icon-white"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Rails 4 and Bootstrap 3, here's how to create a delete button using `link_to` or `button_to`.

Note that I'm using [Haml](http://haml.info/) instead of Erb.

In your view:

```
- @users.each do |user|
  = link_to content_tag(:i, ' Delete', class: "glyphicon glyphicon-trash"),
    users_path(user),
    class: "btn btn-danger",
    method: :delete,
    data: { confirm: "Delete user #{user.username}?" }
```

You can also replace the `content_tag` part with

```
raw('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> Delete</i>'),
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me, (and with confirm message)

```
<%= button_to "/home/delete?cardId="+card.id.to_s, data: { confirm:'Are you sure you want to delete?' }  do %>
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
<% end%>
```

this generate

```
<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/home/delete?cardId=15">
 <button data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete?" type="submit">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
 </button>
</form>
```