# Adding Bootstrap icon to button in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add an icon to a button in ruby on rails. Currently I've tried the following:

```
<%= button_to raw("<i class=\"icon-arrow-up\"></i>"),
{:controller => 'events', :action => "upvoteEvent", :method => "put",
:id => @event.id, :uid => current_user.id},
{:class => "btn btn-success"}%>
```

which produces the following html:

```
<form action="/events/upvoteEvent?id=17&amp;method=put&amp;uid=7" class="button_to" method="post"><div><input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="<i class="icon-arrow-up"></i>" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="FsVUPiYl0cK666pn8hqo6AU9/HK0CweZ/nsXqwOWZzU=" /></div></form>
```

I've followed the solution posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10468935/1385324, but it won't work for me. I have also tested that the Bootstrap CSS is working, by simply inserting an icon anywhere else on the site.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you cant set a icon for a `button_to` helper. It would require you to call `.html_safe` or `raw()` but thats not possible as far as I know since the string you have to call it on isnt accessible.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys, ended up with modifying my own html-output which made it work:

```
<form action="/events/upvoteEvent?id=<%= @event.id.to_s%>&amp;method=put&amp;uid=<%= current_user.id.to_s%>" class="button_to" method="post">
    <button type="submit" value="upvote" class="btn btn-success">
        <i class="icon-arrow-up"></i>
    </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 12):

You could also try this:

```
<%= link_to 'Upvote <i class="icon-arrow-up"></i>'.html_safe, 'events/upvoteEvent', class: => 'btn btn-success' %>
```

or for a true submit button, this:

```
<%= button_tag(:type => 'submit', :class => 'btn btn-success') do %>
Upvote <i class="icon-up-arrow icon-white"></i>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for a link that looks like a button, you could do something like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Upvote <i class="icon-arrow-up"></i>', 'events/upvote', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
```

If you want to use it for a form, you could do something like this with `button_tag`, `submit_tag`, or `f.submit`.

```
<%= submit_tag 'Upvote <i class="icon-arrow-up"></i>', html: { class: 'btn btn-success' } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look right at the bottom of this [page on the Twitter Bootstrap website](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons), you will notice there are some buttons with icons on them.  You can then view the source to see how they have done it - I would say that would be a great starting point.

Answer (score 0):

A better and cleaner way would be:

```
= link_to 'events/upvoteEvent', class: => 'btn btn-success' do
   Upvote
   <i class="icon-arrow-up"></i>'.html_safe
```