# Devise/ Delete user Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am creating a form for an admin to go in and list, edit and delete users. I have tried many different variations for deleting a user and nothing works. I am wondering if it is because I need to use `devise_for :users` and `resources :users` in my routes.rb. This is because I have uploads/attachments linked to users. But here is my link

```
<%= link_to 'Delete',user, :method => 'delete',  :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>
```

And my routes.rb

```
# devise_for :users
devise_for :users do
  get "/users/sign_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_user_session
end
resources :users  do
  resources :attachments
end
```

The error I am receiving is `The action 'destroy' could not be found for UsersController.`

But my users controller has

```
def destroy
  @user = User.find(params[:id]).destroy
  redirect_to admin_index, :flash => { :success => 'User was successfully deleted.' }
end
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Devise.  Looks similar to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606860/rails-3-link-to-to-destroy-not-working).  The answer there suggests using a button, which is probably a good idea, but a link works in Rails as well.  It might be an issue with your Ajax JavaScript driver.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using ajax for the requests, the problem is taht you ar using a `link_to`

In order to send the :method => 'delete' you have to use a button, jus like this:

```
<%= button_to 'Delete', user, :method => 'delete',  :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>
```

Because destructive action must be performed with a form submission:

http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html#checklist

Comment: Please check two things, first, use the rake routes and send me your routes and second just check if you are not closing the controller berfore defining de destroy method.

Comment: Here is a portion of my users controller with destroy

Comment: The controller is closed.My rake routes is really long but for users `users#index POST/users(.:format)                               users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                           users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                      users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                           users#show
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                           users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                           users#destroy`