# Rails destroy method strange behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have controller destroy method

```
def destroy
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @category.destroy
    redirect_to backend_categories_path
end
```

and in view two different destroying links

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', backend_category_path(category), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<%= button_to 'Destroy', backend_category_path(category), :confirm => "are you sure?", :method => :delete %>
```

problems are:

1. 1st link doesnt work, it shows record not delete
2. 2nd link does work but dont ask me if i really want to delete
   record.

jquery gem is installed
whats problem ?

rails version is 3.2.13

Comment: Does the first link still hit the controller method?  E.g. if you put a log message in the controller like `puts 'logging here'` will it still show up?

Comment: From this question, it also looks like you should always use a `button_to` for a delete:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606860/rails-3-link-to-to-destroy-not-working

Comment: Be careful with links to destroys; they might be crawled.

Comment: For the second link issue, here is a similar problem, maybe this solution could help: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/471271

Comment: Thank you very much, solution is i had bad 
`javascript_include_tag` (yes, sorry :D) in html layout
that thing with crawler is interesting, but it is on site needed authorization so it shouldnt be dangerous other way i think i can post via ajax. (im new so i cant answer this topic now but i will)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you should not have any destructive actions accessible via `GET` request. Among other concerns, you run the risk of the things being deleted when your site is crawled.

That said, your use of `button_to` is syntactically correct. The failure of the confirmation message to work is likely attributable to a Javascript error. Have you ensured that you have the following in your `<head>`?

```
# app/views/home/index.html.erb
<head>
    <%= javascript_include_tag(:defaults) %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

in the head of your application layout have you added **<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>** ? like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>title of page</title>
.....
.....
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> 

<%= csrf_meta_tag %>

</head>
....
```

and be sure that you have the following lines in your *app/assets/application.js* file :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs 
//= require_tree .
```

i think that you can also replace `<%= button_to Destroy',backend_category_path(category), ....` with `<%= button_to 'Destroy', category, ....`