# Trying to delete comments in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to learn Rails by building a simple blog. Following along with a tutorial, I have made it possible to add comments with AJAX. However, now I'm trying to make deleting the comments possible and it doesn't work. I keep getting error messages like "No route matches [GET] "/posts/1/comments/3"".

These are my routes:

```
post_comments_path  POST    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)  comments#create
post_comment_path   DELETE  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)  comments#destroy
posts_path  GET     /posts(.:format)    posts#index
    POST    /posts(.:format)    posts#create
new_post_path   GET     /posts/new(.:format)    posts#new
edit_post_path  GET     /posts/:id/edit(.:format)   posts#edit
post_path   GET     /posts/:id(.:format)    posts#show
    PATCH   /posts/:id(.:format)    posts#update
    PUT     /posts/:id(.:format)    posts#update
    DELETE  /posts/:id(.:format)    posts#destroy
root_path   GET     /   posts#index
```

This is my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end

  root 'posts#index'
end
```

_comment.html.erb:

```
<%= div_for comment do %>
  <p>
    <strong>
      Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago
    </strong>
    <br/>
    <%= comment.body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= link_to 'Delete', [comment.post, comment],
               :method => :delete,
               data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
                %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

And the comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.create!(comment_params)
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to @post }
            format.js
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.find(comment_params)
        @comment.destroy

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to @post }
            format.js
        end
    end

    private

    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
    end
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Update: I did have to change 'link_to' to 'button_to', but I also had in mistake in finding my comment in the 'destroy'-action which I had to fix.

Comment: possible duplicate of [rails 3 - link\_to to destroy not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606860/rails-3-link-to-to-destroy-not-working)

Comment: Do you have the line `//= require jquery_ujs` in your `application.js` file?

Comment: The answer to the linked question is "use button_to instead of link_to".  Should be working for rails 4 as well.

Comment: @bdares Thanks! I just tried replacing "link_to" with "button_to", but then I get this error: "param is missing or the value is empty: comment
Extracted source (around line #25):
 def comment_params
     params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
 end
end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to find a comment using the `comment_params`.

Instead of `@comment = @post.comments.find(comment_params)` in your destroy action, try `@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])`

Comment: Also, once you get this up and running you'll want to add `remote: true` to the `link_to` helper

Comment: Thanks so much! Doing this and using button_to instead of link_to made it work!