# Rails on windows destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using rails 3 on windows. I used scaffolding to create a "party" MVC but the destroy action does not work for some reason and redirects instead to the show page.

View:
`<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', party, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>`

Controller:

`def destroy`
`@party = Party.find(params[:id])`
`@party.destroy`

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to(parties_url) }
  format.xml  { head :ok }
end
```

`end`

Whats wrong?

Comment: Does it ever show the confirmation? What browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the javascript/csrf tags in your layout:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

(See [Delete link sends "Get" instead of "Delete" in Rails 3 view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774925/delete-link-sends-get-instead-of-delete-in-rails-3-view/3775095#3775095))