# rails / bootstrap delete link issue: data-method delete not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I am using gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails' for rails bootstrap

I have a few links on a page
Rails code

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', swimming_classschedule, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>

 <li> <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :class => 'navbar-link'  %> </li>
```

html code:

```
     <a href="/users/sign_out" class="navbar-link" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Logout</a>

<td><a href="/swimming/students/1" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a></td>

      <td><a href="/swimming/students/3" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a></td>
```

Whenever I click to delete a student I got logged out. I am totally confused

Comment: And if you remove logout link, what happens then? You use Devise? Isn't the log saying `WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity`

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem.. I read in the forums that it was due to javascript issues.

In application.js, I previously removed the original files because I thought they weren't needed as I was using bootstrap.js.  I put it back in the file and now the delete method works again!

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: I added only jquery_ujs after jquery, which is the responsible for that

Comment: Hi @juanpastas, Thank you for your commennt!
I have added the `jquery_ujs` after jquery, then it works perfectly.

Comment: In my case I had to do something a little bit different. I added this to my application.js file:
`import Rails from '@rails/ujs';
Rails.start();`

Answer (score 2):

based on this answer [Delete link sends "Get" instead of "Delete" in Rails 3 view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774925/delete-link-sends-get-instead-of-delete-in-rails-3-view)

I added

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

in header, which fixed the issue