# Ruby On Rails errors with javascript_include_tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

So my issue, from what I can tell, seems to be that ruby is not loading all of its javascript files as I am not getting confirm messages and link_to with method: :delete does nothing for me.

With the default set up provided to me rails new

views/layouts/application.html.erb head section is as follows.

```
<head>
  <title>Myrubyblog</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true%>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Which gives me the error

```
Started GET "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-27 02:14:57 -0600
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
  Post Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
  Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (11.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 76ms (Views: 54.0ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)


Started GET "/stylesheets/default.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-27 02:14:58 -0600

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/default.css"):
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/
_trace.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_
route.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_
table.html.erb (9.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/
routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (46.1ms)


Started GET "/javascripts/default.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-27 02:14:58 -0600

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/default.js"):
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/
_trace.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_
route.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_
table.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/
routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (35.8ms)
```

This error also occurs when I change the stylescheet_link_tag and javascript_include_tag to use :default instead of 'default'.

This error seems to be occuring because /javascripts/default.js doesn't exist, so I found these two articles which said that :default is no longer supported.

[Rails 4 link_to Destroy not working in Getting Started tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154916/rails-4-link-to-destroy-not-working-in-getting-started-tutorial)

[Delete link sends "Get" instead of "Delete" in Rails 3 view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774925/delete-link-sends-get-instead-of-delete-in-rails-3-view)

After changing 'default' to 'application' I got the following error.

views/layouts/application.html.erb head section is as follows.

```
<head>
  <title>Myrubyblog</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true%>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Which gives me the error

```
Started GET "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-27 02:26:28 -0600
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
  Post Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
  Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (12.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2198ms

ActionView::Template::Error (TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
  (in c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)):
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>Myrubyblog</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>
    9: <body>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___474145341_51059580'


  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/
_trace.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/
_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/
template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (20.0ms)
```

Does anyone have any idea what my issue is?

My routes and gemfile for reference if need be.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'categories/index'

  get 'categories/edit'

  get 'categories/new'

  get 'categories/show'

  get 'home/index'

  resources :posts
  resources :categories

  root 'home#index'
end
```

gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

Comment: It should be `:defaults`, I guess.

Comment: I've tried using :defaults too. All it does is try to open /javascripts/defaults.js which also doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this error?

Answer (score 6):

change your 'defaults' in both lines back to 'application'

insert this in gem file:

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
```

then run this in command prompt:

```
bundle update coffee-script-source
```

fixed my issues, hope it fixes yours too :)

Comment: why 1.8.0 ? I had to downgrade from 1.10.0 to 1.8.0... why ? what is happening ? I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: @RareFever I dont think 'coffee-script-source 1.9 and > work on windows.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Windows... Thanks for the answer !!

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your 'defaults' in both lines back to 'application'
2. Insert this in gem file:
   gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
3. Then run this in command prompt:
   bundle update coffee-script-source

This answer by Figjeti also worked for me. :)

Comment: don't add thank you as an answer. This is more comment than answer.