# Cannot implement delete in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following this [tutorial](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i1:-form-based-workflow) to built a simple blogger side.

However, I am unable to implement the delete function as shown by the tutorial.

The steps given are as follows:

> Let’s define the destroy method in our ArticlesController so it:
>
> - Uses params[:id] to find the article in the database
> - Calls .destroy on that object
> - Redirects to the articles index page
>
> Do that now on your own and test it.

This is my code:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    include ArticlesHelper

    def index
        @articles = Article.all
    end

    def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @article = Article.new
    end

    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)
        @article.save
        flash.notice = "Article '#{@article.title}' Created!"
        redirect_to article_path(@article) 
    end

    def destroy
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        @article.destroy
        redirect_to articles_path
    end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @article.title %></h1>
<p><%= @article.body %></p>
<%= link_to "<< Back to Articles List", articles_path %>
<%= link_to "delete", article_path(@article), method: :delete %>
```

article_helper.rb

```
module ArticlesHelper

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
  end

end
```

I have browsed through other solutions online but I don't see any code which I might have missed out.

In my case, clicking on the delete link only results in the page refreshing.

Comment: why `private`? move it up

Comment: Thanks, i was following the altered tutorial on github, i updated the code as per the newer tutorial but it still doesn't work.

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: add the logs too

Comment: There isn't one, the page reloads upon clicking the delete button and nothing happens. I am quite new to rails, are the logs reflected in a file or directly at the console? Also, if it helps, the other methods work perfectly fine.

Comment: they appear in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue:

The setup was running on Windows. I applied a [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421547/rails-execjsprogramerror-in-pageshome) previously as the page would not load.

This fix caused the error here :

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/javascripts/default.js"):

The way to fix this is to undo the previous changes above and follow the fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760633/ruby-on-rails-errors-with-javascript-include-tag).

Apparently, coffee-script-source 1.9 and above does not work on Windows.

Comment: a quick suggestion, use linux/ubuntu, ofcourse MacOS is fine too.. :)

Answer (score 2):

`private` methods in controllers are not accessible outside the controller, even to routes. So you'll never be able to route to `destroy` or `article_params` in your current code. If you move your `destroy` method above the `private` keyword, should fix things.

Comment: Thanks, i was following the altered tutorial on github, i updated the code as per the newer tutorial but it still doesn't work.