# heroku proccessing "PUT" and "DELETE" request as "GET", Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, put, http-delete

i just push my latest commit to heroku, and type `heroku open` from my console.
when i try to click my delete link , it doesn't deleted as expected, instead i get

`Processing by GamesController#show as HTML"`

i try to make sure by look at browser source code , i cant see any problem with my code

```
<a class="btn btn-default" data-confirm="Are you sure?" 
   data-method="delete" href="games/3" rel="nofollow">
```

is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: What's the name of the method in your controller that handles deletion? Is it `destroy`?

Comment: i use this   <a class="btn btn-default" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="games/<%=game.id%>" rel="nofollow"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>  and it works on localhost

Comment: Please read my comment again. I asked for the name of the **method** in the **controller**. Also, this might help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774925/delete-link-sends-get-instead-of-delete-in-rails-3-view

Comment: yes it is   "destroy"

Comment: my application.html.erb also contain <%= csrf_meta_tags %> all the time

Comment: @Muhammad_Sigit_Dude Did you solve it? and how?

Answer (score 2):

The `DELETE` method is provided by Rails jQuery UJS adapter.

Make sure `//= require jquery_ujs` is in `application.js`.

Comment: He says it works on localhost. So this line must be there. It's auto-generated, anyway.

Comment: i'm sure //= require jquery_ujs is in my application.js, :(

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Good point. Didn't notice the localhost comment. Could be a precompilation issue then.

Comment: @Muhammad_Sigit_Dude: Check your browser console for javascript errors, make sure you have cleared your local cache?

Comment: @Muhammad_Sigit_Dude: Please post the contents of `application.js`. Looks like jquery is loaded after bootstrap.

Comment: `//= require angular
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree 
`

Comment: @Muhammad_Sigit_Dude: Move `require bootstrap` below `require jquery_ujs`

Comment: `//= require angular //= require bootstrap //= require jquery //= require jquery_ujs //= require turbolinks //= require_tree`

Comment: just pushed new commit and still have same issue, after i changed to this:` //= require angular
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree `

Comment: @fylooi: also angular should be after jquery, I imagine. Although, this should not be causing this problem

Comment: @Muhammad_Sigit_Dude: Are you running asset precompile manually?

Comment: i've tried solution like precompile assets manualy. doesnt work

Comment: @Muhammad_Sigit_Dude: If you have precompiled assets before, heroku will always serve the last precompiled version. You need to run `rake assets:clobber` both on localhost and heroku.