# Rails Puma Server: Undefined `extract_multipart' or `before_create' on logout action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, puma, mongoid6

I'm unable to logout out of my own page because I get a `undefined method` Puma error whenever I try. Most of the times it's `extract_multipart`, but I've also seen `before_create`.

This is what is shown in the blank page whenever I click logout

```
Puma caught this error: undefined method `extract_multipart' for Rack::Multipart:Module (NoMethodError)
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/request.rb:472:in `parse_multipart'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/request.rb:335:in `POST'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/method_override.rb:39:in `method_override_param'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/method_override.rb:27:in `method_override'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/method_override.rb:15:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.2/lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.2/lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.2/lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

The way I'm managing log-outs is with

```
<%= link_to(logout_path, method: 'delete', class: 'dropdown-item') do %>
<!-- ... -->
<% end %>
```

Where the route is defined as `delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'`, and the controller / action is

```
def destroy
  session[:id] = nil
  redirect_to '/login'
end
```

The other error I have only caught once or twice and all I have is a screenshot

[Puma: undefined `before_create`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfCWd.png)

Any ideas on what might be causing this? Thanks beforehand :)

### Edit

As per request, here's the `Enumerable` concern, which I'm not actually using because I'm also having issues with that (GH issue submitted on auto-inc repository)

```
require 'autoinc'

module Enumerable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include Mongoid::Autoinc
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :n, as: :number, type: Integer

    increments :number
  end
end
```

And the only `before_create` I'm using is within a completely unrelated module...

### Edit 2

Tried updating puma to `3.7.0`, didn't fix it. Although it didn't break it further...

Comment: Could you please add the enumerable concern and the place you are using the `before_create` callback?

Comment: Done, although as I said the `before_create` is on a model that is unrelated to users / sessions

Answer (score 0):

Answer obtained from

[Delete link sends "Get" instead of "Delete" in Rails 3 view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774925/delete-link-sends-get-instead-of-delete-in-rails-3-view)

I needed to add the `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>` to my `head`.