# Rails: cannot find delete method. Rendering get method instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add ability to delete Wallet model in my User panel. However for some reason Rails reads it as a GET method and rise this error:

> No route matches [GET] "/wallets/1"

My view file:

```
= link_to 'Remove wallet', wallet_path(@wallet), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

my wallets controller:

```
class WalletsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @wallet = current_user.wallets.create(wallet_params)
        if @wallet.save
            redirect_to wallets_index_path
            flash[:notice] = "New wallet has been added successfully"
        else
            render 'home/wallets_new'
            flash[:alert] = "Your wallet could not be added. Please try again"
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @wallet.delete
        redirect_to wallets_index_path, notice: 'Post has been deleted successfully'
    end
```

routes:

```
  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      root to: 'home#wallets_index', as: :unauthenticated_root
      resources :wallets, only: [:create, :destroy]
    end

    unauthenticated :user do
      root to: 'home#index', as: :authenticated_root
    end
  end
```

and rake routes:

> wallets POST   /wallets(.:format)             wallets#create
>
> wallet DELETE /wallets/:id(.:format)         wallets#destroy

I am not sure how to handle this error since I explicitly told Rails to use DELETE method via method: :delete in my link_to helper. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have

`<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>`

in your application.html.erb?

if not this may be the cause. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774925/delete-link-sends-get-instead-of-delete-in-rails-3-view)

Comment: It turns out that somehow I didn't have rails-ujs included. Thank you